# How to create ElevatedButton from RaisedButton?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

There are so many properties in the `RaisedButton` whose equivalent I can't find yet in the `ElevatedButton`. So, how can I convert or replicate a `RaisedButton` (with all the properties) to the new `ElevatedButton`?

Like:

```dart
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
  disabledColor: Colors.indigo,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  disabledTextColor: Colors.grey,
  hoverColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
  splashColor: Colors.black,
  elevation: 12.0,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  shape: StadiumBorder(),
  child: Text('Button'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a new class named `MyElevatedButton`.

```dart
class MyElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final Widget child;
  final Color? color;
  final Color? disabledColor;
  final Color? textColor;
  final Color? disabledTextColor;
  final Color? hoverColor;
  final Color? splashColor;
  final double? elevation;
  final double? disabledElevation;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? padding;
  final OutlinedBorder? shape;

  MyElevatedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
    this.color,
    this.disabledColor,
    this.textColor,
    this.disabledTextColor,
    this.hoverColor,
    this.splashColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.disabledElevation,
    this.padding,
    this.shape,
  }) : super(key: key);

  bool _isPressed(Set<MaterialState> states) => states.contains(MaterialState.pressed);
  bool _isDisabled(Set<MaterialState> states) => states.contains(MaterialState.disabled);
  bool _isHovered(Set<MaterialState> states) => states.contains(MaterialState.hovered);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final style = ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) {
        if (_isDisabled(states)) {
          return disabledColor;
        } else if (_isHovered(states)) {
          return hoverColor;
        }
        return color;
      }),
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) {
        if (_isDisabled(states)) return disabledTextColor;
      }),
      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) {
        if (_isPressed(states)) return splashColor;
      }),
      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<double?>((states) {
        if (_isDisabled(states)) return disabledElevation;
        return elevation;
      }),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder?>(shape),
      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry?>(padding),
    );

    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      style: style,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the example code (one is `RaisedButton` and the other is `ElevatedButton` using the same properties)

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final onPressed = () {};
  final child = Text('Button');
  final color = Colors.indigoAccent;
  final disabledColor = Colors.indigo;
  final textColor = Colors.white;
  final disabledTextColor = Colors.grey;
  final hoverColor = Colors.pinkAccent;
  final splashColor = Colors.black;
  final elevation = 8.0;
  final disabledElevation = 0.0;
  final shape = StadiumBorder();
  final padding = EdgeInsets.all(12);
  
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('RaisedButton'),
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: onPressed,
            color: color,
            disabledColor: disabledColor,
            textColor: textColor,
            disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
            hoverColor: hoverColor,
            splashColor: splashColor,
            elevation: elevation,
            padding: padding,
            shape: shape,
            child: child,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Text('ElevatedButton'),
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          MyElevatedButton(
            onPressed: onPressed,
            color: color,
            disabledColor: disabledColor,
            textColor: textColor,
            disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
            hoverColor: hoverColor,
            splashColor: splashColor,
            elevation: elevation,
            disabledElevation: disabledElevation,
            padding: padding,
            shape: shape,
            child: child,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I covered most of the common properties but not all, feel free to add your own because all properties work the similar way. The only thing which was not replicable was the `highlightColor` of the `RaisedButton` because the `overlayColor`'s set only reflects one property at a time and has precedence over the `backgroundColor`.

[image]

Disabled state:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should instead use the `theme` property of your `MaterialApp()` and the corresponding button themes, for example:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.blue,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)
        )
    ),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.black,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        )
      )
   ),
 ),
)
```

For individual button styles you can then use:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    minimumSize: Size(30.0, 36.0),
    primary: Colors.green,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
       borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
    ),
  ),
),
```

also see [New Buttons and Button Themes](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

Comment: You should instead use the theme property of your MaterialApp()" -- Not a good solution as it would change the colors of all the descendant buttons. Second, `ElevatedButton.styleFrom` doesn't have all the properties I asked in the question. For example setting `primary`, `onSurface` applies the passed color to the `backgroundColor` property and you will see the `disabledColor` isn't exactly replicating the one used in `RaisedButton`. I already knew these solutions which *just works* before I wrote my long answer.

Comment: You can have a ThemeData apply to only a single button using Theme( ... child: yourbutton).